# The best practice for checking variable

Tags: php, wordpress

Which one is the best practice to use the argument values?
Below is the php code I wrote inside a Wordpress theme.

```
function kpn_page_banner($args) {
    if (!$args['title']) {
        $args['title'] = the_title();
    }

    !$args['title'] && $args['title'] = the_title();

    $title = $args['title'] ? $args['title'] : the_title();


    // ... 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not recommended to access `array` `keys` without checking its existence. If you do in that way you can get some `Notices`.

```
if(!isset($args['title']) || ( isset($args['title']) && trim($args['title']) === '')) {
     $args['title'] = the_title();
}
```

Also, don't ever try to reduce the size of an `if` statement by excluding some conditions that are so important, like `isset` is in your case.

> Check out more http://php.net/manual/ro/function.isset.php

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll apply your suggestion next time I code